# Simple MySQL SELECT fails with error 1054 Unknown Column

Tags: php, mysql, select

I did research on this question and nothing I've read in the MySQL manual, in MySQL bug reports, in Stack Overflow, or in other forums has helped so far.

I have a simple mysql select query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Toyota` WHERE `Toyota`.`CollisionEstimatingID` = '22028589';
```

This query fails with mysql error code 1054

> Unknown column `Toyota.CollisionEstimatingID` in the `WHERE` clause

This column DOES exist, I've checked the spelling of the database, table and column at least 30 times now.  I even deleted my database and reimported. I have tried it with the backticks and without backticks, with alias' and without alias' I've tried it with explicitly named table.column syntax, and without the explicit syntax, I've tried mixing and matching all the stuff I've mentioned (backticks on the table, but not the column, on the column but not the table name), and nothing seems to work. It fails when I execute it from the mysql CLI on Ubuntu 12.04, it fails from my PHP 5.3 code, and it fails inside of phpMyAdmin. I am ready to flip a table.

When I try this though:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Toyota`;
```

This works without any problems?  Good god, MySQL is such a tease...

Here is the table setup as derived from `show create database Toyota;`

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Toyota` (
  `CollisionEstimatingID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OE_part_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

An interesting note -- I wonder if it could be character encoding problems? I did get it to work ONCE in phpMyAdmin by using the `show create table Toyota` and deleting everything but the "CollisionEstimatingID" and used that to form the SELECT statement. But when I tried cutting and pasting, no dice.

I tried recreating the database and tables using the utf8 character set to see if that would help, but it didn't help.  I tried copying to text out of the phpMyAdmin window and into my source code -- that produced some funky characters at the beginning of the column name -- kinda like this: `>>?CollisionEstimatingID` only it was an 'i' with an umlaut + a double right chevron and an upside down question mark.

I'm stumped. Anyone want to test their programming mettle and help a brother out?

Comment: How were you creating the table? Hand type? File import?

Comment: @Passerby -- I created the table programmatically I have a huge collection of .txt export files to parse through and import and I have to write queries against this stuff.

Comment: Like "ï»¿"? This is the UTF-8 BOM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Might have to clean the files 1st.

Comment: @KillerX -- yes just like that!

Comment: @KillerX please post your response as the answer and I'll accept that. I think this is exactly the error -- that column name is the first name in the .txt file, I open the .txt dump file with C++, read the first line, parse it, and turn it into a create table statement, I must be picking up the BOM and it becomes part of the column name... no wonder my SQL query won't match...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like "ï»¿"?

This is the UTF-8 BOM (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

You probably need to clean the input files first.

Comment: thank you sir! you made my night and educated me to boot! Now I can finally go to sleep :P

Comment: You are welcome (Its a relatively common PHP problem, when you get things like "output started at line 1" and there is nothing in line 1 :) )

Answer (score 0):

Your codes doesn't have any problem as i have did some testing with my SQL Server.
May be try this

```
SELECT * FROM Toyota WHERE Toyota.CollisionEstimatingID = '22028589'
```